# how to pass dynamic parameter in external js url in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal

We need to pass dynamic parameters(API Key) in external JS(Google MAP API URL) in the modulename.libraries.yml file. because, API Key is stored in Drupal Config form by Administrator.

modulename.libraries.yml :
`google.mapaddr:
  js:
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-KEY]&libraries=places: { type: external }`

Please guide us to pass the Config variable to External JS parameters in Drupal 8 standards.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Add dynamic library definitions.

Use  [hook_library_info_build()](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj33LOxvb3TAhVLuY8KHZRBABsQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fapi%2Fdrupal%2Fcore!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php%2Ffunction%2Fhook_library_info_build%2F8.2.x&usg=AFQjCNHhjcpC2NsnLRdhwfM7o14BmjPBnw) function

```
/**
 * Implements hook_library_info_build().
 */

function my_module_library_info_build() {

  $config = \Drupal::config('my_module.settings');
  $api_key = $config->get('my_module.api_key');

  $libraries = [];

  $libraries['my_module_js'] = [
    'version' => '1.x',
    'header' => true,
    'js' => [
      'https://my.external.com/' => [
        'type' => 'external',
        'minified' => true,
        'attributes' => [
          'key' => "$api_key",
          'async' => "async",
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  return $libraries;
}
```

I hope it may be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It works after modified as per my below comments to make it run properly.

Answer (score 1):

As per above suggestion, updated code(below) and it is working fine.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_library_info_build()
 */
function my_module_library_info_build() {
  $config = \Drupal::config('my_module.settings');
  $api_key = $config->get('api_key');
  $libraries = [];
  $libraries['my_module.libraryid'] = [
    'version' => '1.x',
    'js' => [
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='.$api_key.'&libraries=places' => [
            'type' => 'external',
        ],
    ],
  ];
  return $libraries;
}
```

Also, we could include this dynamic library as "dependencies" of another libraries in modulename.libraries.yml file like below format.

```
custom-js:
  version: VERSION
    js:
    js/custom.js: {}
      dependencies:
        - core/jquery
        - my_module/my_module.libraryid
```

Answer (score 0):

Above suggestion did the trick for me, but for my use case I still needed the language parameter that is dynamically added depending on which language you currently are on the website, so If used the hook added in the comment above and also added the following hook:

```
function hook_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  foreach($javascript as &$js_file) {
    if (strpos($js_file['data'], 'maps.googleapis.com') !== FALSE) {
      $js_file['data'] .= '&language=' . \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
    }
  }
}
```